# Triangle $X'\to X\to X''\to\Sigma X'$ splits if $X\simeq X'\oplus X''$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Given a commutative ring $R$ and a distinguished triangle $X'\to X\to X''\xrightarrow e\Sigma X'$ in the derived category $D(R)$, where $X',X,X''$ are perfect complexes. If we have an equivalence $X\simeq X'\oplus X''$ in $D(R)$, is it true that the distinguished triangle is equivalent to the canonical split distinguished triangle $X'\to X'\oplus X''\to X''\xrightarrow0\Sigma X'$? Or equivalently, is it true that the extension map $e\colon X''\to\Sigma X$ is null-homotopic?

Maybe we can weaken the perfectness to almost-perfectness (in the literature, almost perfect complexes are sometimes also called pseudo-coherent complexes). I would like to refer to Lurie's [Higher Algebra](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf) section 7.2.4 for the terminology.

I also wonder whether there are similar results for non-commutative rings, or ring spectra.

This is related to an old [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1845683/23875). In the case that $X',X,X''$ are discrete, there are several studies in the literature. For example, Guralnick [showed](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379581903001/pdf?md5=4d04fc84e4aca4caa73142a9562226c4&pid=1-s2.0-0024379581903001-main.pdf&_valck=1) that this is the case when $X',X,X''$ are finitely presented $R$-modules. On the other hand, a finiteness condition is [necessary](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/135444/23875).

Comment: A more general result than Guralnick's is Theorem 4.4 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.3855: Any exact sequence $M \to N \to C\to 0$ of finitely generated modules over a noetherian (not necessarily commutative) ring splits iff $N \cong M \oplus C$.

Comment: @tj_ Thanks. This is interesting. In short, it is saying that the data of (well-founded) partial ordered sets of submodules are enough to show this (instead of classical passing to localizations and completions).